# iOS: This process has exceeded the maximum allowable number of active process assertions

Tags: ios, objective-c

We have developed an app where a number of file downloads take place. The error occurs randomly when the process is on going on. I have done research about a similar issue like "active assertions beyond permitted time" and it's pretty straightforward. What can be causing this issue? The error report is as follows. We are using [JGDownloadAcceleration](https://github.com/JonasGessner/JGDownloadAcceleration) and the download occurs with multipart download.

```
Incident Identifier: 239DA305-5FDF-4A30-89B3-4446F9AE30D1
CrashReporter Key:   e098bda19a9d7115be19b2cd34281cc9cd13aa21
Hardware Model:      iPad4,2
Process:             Sales Aid [1345]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/176AB0ED-44CD-4454-9096-47DB42663789/Sales Aid.app/Sales Aid
Version:             3.7.47 (3.7.47)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]


Date/Time:           2017-09-29 10:36:22.4001 +0530
Launch Time:         2017-09-29 08:56:13.0757 +0530
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.0 (15A372)
Baseband Version:    8.01.00
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0xbada5e47
Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, This process has exceeded the maximum allowable number of active process assertions
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000185b68bc4 0x185b68000 + 3012
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000185b68a3c 0x185b68000 + 2620
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186017ce4 0x185f2e000 + 957668
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001860158b0 0x185f2e000 + 948400
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185f362d8 0x185f2e000 + 33496
5   GraphicsServices                0x0000000187dc7f84 0x187dbd000 + 44932
6   UIKit                           0x000000018f4e2880 0x18f46f000 + 473216
7   Sales Aid                       0x00000001003919b4 0x10038c000 + 22964
8   libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000185a5a56c 0x185a59000 + 5484

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000185b89150 0x185b68000 + 135504
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185c9ed40 0x185c9a000 + 19776
2   PSPDFKit                        0x00000001018dc06c 0x101444000 + 4817004
3   PSPDFKit                        0x00000001018da03c 0x101444000 + 4808764
4   PSPDFKit                        0x0000000101a97988 0x101444000 + 6633864
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185c9c32c 0x185c9a000 + 9004
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185c9c1f8 0x185c9a000 + 8696
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185c9ac38 0x185c9a000 + 3128

Thread 2 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000185b68bc4 0x185b68000 + 3012
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000185b68a3c 0x185b68000 + 2620
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186017ce4 0x185f2e000 + 957668
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001860158b0 0x185f2e000 + 948400
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185f362d8 0x185f2e000 + 33496
5   Foundation                      0x000000018695e6e4 0x186952000 + 50916
6   Foundation                      0x000000018697dafc 0x186952000 + 178940
7   UIKit                           0x000000019002e02c 0x18f46f000 + 12316716
8   Foundation                      0x0000000186a5f860 0x186952000 + 1103968
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185c9c32c 0x185c9a000 + 9004
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185c9c1f8 0x185c9a000 + 8696
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185c9ac38 0x185c9a000 + 3128

Thread 3 name:  com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000185b68bc4 0x185b68000 + 3012
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000185b68a3c 0x185b68000 + 2620
2   Sales Aid                       0x00000001005685cc 0x10038c000 + 1951180
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185c9c32c 0x185c9a000 + 9004
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185c9c1f8 0x185c9a000 + 8696
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185c9ac38 0x185c9a000 + 3128

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000185b68bc4 0x185b68000 + 3012
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000185b68a3c 0x185b68000 + 2620
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186017ce4 0x185f2e000 + 957668
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001860158b0 0x185f2e000 + 948400
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185f362d8 0x185f2e000 + 33496
5   CFNetwork                       0x000000018669fb40 0x1865f1000 + 715584
6   Foundation                      0x0000000186a5f860 0x186952000 + 1103968
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185c9c32c 0x185c9a000 + 9004
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185c9c1f8 0x185c9a000 + 8696
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185c9ac38 0x185c9a000 + 3128

Thread 5 name:  JGDownloadAcceleration
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000185b68bc4 0x185b68000 + 3012
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000185b68a3c 0x185b68000 + 2620
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186017ce4 0x185f2e000 + 957668
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001860158b0 0x185f2e000 + 948400
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185f362d8 0x185f2e000 + 33496
5   Foundation                      0x000000018695e6e4 0x186952000 + 50916
6   Foundation                      0x00000001869b062c 0x186952000 + 386604
7   Sales Aid                       0x00000001004b3ef0 0x10038c000 + 1212144
8   Foundation                      0x0000000186a5f860 0x186952000 + 1103968
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185c9c32c 0x185c9a000 + 9004
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185c9c1f8 0x185c9a000 + 8696
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185c9ac38 0x185c9a000 + 3128

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185c9ac2c 0x185c9a000 + 3116

Thread 7 name:  Dispatch queue: cocoa.lumberjack
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000185b68c00 0x185b68000 + 3072
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001859f73d4 0x1859f4000 + 13268
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001859f8328 0x1859f4000 + 17192
3   Sales Aid                       0x0000000100487678 0x10038c000 + 1029752
4   Sales Aid                       0x0000000100485d90 0x10038c000 + 1023376
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001859f5088 0x1859f4000 + 4232
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001859f5048 0x1859f4000 + 4168
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001859fee48 0x1859f4000 + 44616
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001859ff7d8 0x1859f4000 + 47064
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000185a00200 0x1859f4000 + 49664
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000185a084a0 0x1859f4000 + 83104
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185c9afe0 0x185c9a000 + 4064
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185c9ac30 0x185c9a000 + 3120

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185c9ac2c 0x185c9a000 + 3116

Thread 9 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000185b8a800 0x185b68000 + 141312
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000185a108f8 0x1859f4000 + 116984
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000185a112c0 0x1859f4000 + 119488
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000185a03018 0x1859f4000 + 61464
4   CoreData                        0x00000001888aeda8 0x1887d4000 + 896424
5   Sales Aid                       0x00000001006503fc 0x10038c000 + 2900988
6   Sales Aid                       0x0000000100650038 0x10038c000 + 2900024
7   Sales Aid                       0x000000010064ff44 0x10038c000 + 2899780
8   Sales Aid                       0x000000010064fec8 0x10038c000 + 2899656
9   Sales Aid                       0x0000000100651594 0x10038c000 + 2905492
10  Sales Aid                       0x0000000100651948 0x10038c000 + 2906440
11  Sales Aid                       0x000000010063dea0 0x10038c000 + 2825888
12  Sales Aid                       0x0000000100812e14 0x10038c000 + 4746772
13  Sales Aid                       0x0000000100812ca8 0x10038c000 + 4746408
14  Sales Aid                       0x00000001006d94f4 0x10038c000 + 3462388
15  Sales Aid                       0x00000001006d25c0 0x10038c000 + 3433920
16  Sales Aid                       0x000000010081fba4 0x10038c000 + 4799396
17  Sales Aid                       0x000000010081e5f0 0x10038c000 + 4793840
18  Sales Aid                       0x000000010081ee80 0x10038c000 + 4796032
19  Sales Aid                       0x00000001004b5268 0x10038c000 + 1217128
20  Foundation                      0x0000000186a38b70 0x186952000 + 945008
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001859f5088 0x1859f4000 + 4232
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001859f5048 0x1859f4000 + 4168
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000185a02378 0x1859f4000 + 58232
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000185a01f10 0x1859f4000 + 57104
25  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185c9b130 0x185c9a000 + 4400
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185c9ac30 0x185c9a000 + 3120

Thread 10 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000185b68c00 0x185b68000 + 3072
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001859f73d4 0x1859f4000 + 13268
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001859f7d84 0x1859f4000 + 15748
3   Sales Aid                       0x000000010083bbbc 0x10038c000 + 4914108
4   Sales Aid                       0x000000010083b6b4 0x10038c000 + 4912820
5   Sales Aid                       0x000000010083b13c 0x10038c000 + 4911420
6   Sales Aid                       0x000000010070bc50 0x10038c000 + 3669072
7   Sales Aid                       0x000000010065db24 0x10038c000 + 2956068
8   Sales Aid                       0x000000010065d70c 0x10038c000 + 2955020
9   Sales Aid                       0x0000000100828ee4 0x10038c000 + 4837092
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001859f5088 0x1859f4000 + 4232
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001859f5048 0x1859f4000 + 4168
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001859fc090 0x1859f4000 + 32912
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000185a021c8 0x1859f4000 + 57800
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000185a01f10 0x1859f4000 + 57104
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185c9b130 0x185c9a000 + 4400
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185c9ac30 0x185c9a000 + 3120

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185c9ac2c 0x185c9a000 + 3116

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185c9ac2c 0x185c9a000 + 3116

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185c9ac2c 0x185c9a000 + 3116

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000010004005   x1: 0x0000000007000806   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000c00
    x4: 0x0000000000002603   x5: 0x00000000ffffffff   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000189f5e7d0
    x8: 0x00000000fffffbbf   x9: 0x0000000007000000  x10: 0x0000000007000100  x11: 0x0000000000000040
   x12: 0xffffffffffffffff  x13: 0x0000000000000001  x14: 0x0a21bd000a21bd00  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0xffffffffffffffe1  x17: 0x00000000ffffffff  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000000
   x20: 0x00000000ffffffff  x21: 0x0000000000002603  x22: 0x0000000000000c00  x23: 0x000000016fa72cf8
   x24: 0x0000000007000806  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000007000806  x27: 0x0000000000000c00
   x28: 0x0000000000000001   fp: 0x000000016fa72bf0   lr: 0x0000000185b68a3c
    sp: 0x000000016fa72ba0   pc: 0x0000000185b68bc4 cpsr: 0x60000000
```

Comment: Have you set `maxConcurrentOperationCount` for your queue? Usually for downloads, 4-5 is a good value.

Comment: Yes, I have already set it to 5.

Comment: The problem could be that you forgot to cancel many on-going tasks in queues when the thumbnails go our the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several days ago, I faced the same error as yours. After a lot of deep code research, I was able to reproduce the error every time and solved it successfully. This error occurred only on iOS 11.0 and later.

It turns out that if a `UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier` is created many many times, the app would crash.

In my test demo, I created a `UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier` in a for-loop and ran it 7000 times (the number could be different according to your code complexity), and this error occurred:

> Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, This process has exceeded the maximum allowable number of active process assertions

Since Xcode cannot catch this termination description, you need to view the device logs manually.

[image: screenshot showing termination description]

So for your case, I guess you have too many concurrent download tasks and each download task has a `UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier`. You can solve it by reducing the number of concurrent download tasks, creating them only as needed, like 10 or fewer.

Below is my test code:

```
for (int  i = 0; i < 7000; i++)
{
    //xxxxxx: any code
    
    NSLog(@"==== %zd", i);

    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundTask;
    backgroundTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^ {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask: backgroundTask];
        backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];
    
    //xxxxxx: any code
}
```